# method to copy images from one directory to another not working

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I have written a function in java to copy images from one directory to another that doesn't seem to work. It throws an `IOException` i.e `C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\C.V (Access is denied)`. What could be the problem. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
public void copyImageFiles(File sourceFile, File destinationDir) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile); 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationDir);  
    FileChannel srcChannel = fis.getChannel();  
    FileChannel destChannel = fos.getChannel();  
    srcChannel.transferTo(0, sourceFile.length(), destChannel); 
    srcChannel.close();  
    destChannel.close();  
    fis.close();  
    fos.close();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\C.V (Access is denied)`

It must be W7 or Vista or W7+. Your program do nt have priviledge to write to `C:\Documents and Settings\Admin`

Either change destination to somewhere else like some other drive. Or run your program as administrator.

refer:

http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/05/11/windows-access-denied-folder-administrator/

icacls http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you logged in as an admin user? Accessing the Admin folder will throw an Exception if your account does not have the required Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\C.V (Access is denied)
```

It's a permission problem.  Try checking out the properties of your folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are not logged in as Administrator. go to user from control panel and check your admin permission.